# Wamp 2 of 3 services running / Apache Error

Tags: wamp, wampserver

Recently started developing websites. I use WAMP for my local host server.
However Wamp is showing me some error today.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OMnO.png)

Here's how it first looked.
Knowing that Wamp is divided into 3 parts: Apache / Php / MySQL
I started to check where could the error log be...

```
[--- File cleaned up by Wampserver ---
--- on 2022-08-19 10:57
[Fri Aug 19 13:58:03.453501 2022\] \[mpm_winnt:notice\] \[pid 2452:tid 908\] AH00455: Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) PHP/7.4.26 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Aug 19 13:58:03.453501 2022\] \[mpm_winnt:notice\] \[pid 2452:tid 908\] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Oct  7 2021 16:27:02
[Fri Aug 19 13:58:03.453501 2022\] \[core:notice\] \[pid 2452:tid 908\] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.51\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.51'
[Fri Aug 19 13:58:03.455495 2022\] \[mpm_winnt:notice\] \[pid 2452:tid 908\] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 22584
[Fri Aug 19 13:58:03.977931 2022\] \[mpm_winnt:notice\] \[pid 22584:tid 444\] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.][2]
```

The error seems to be coming from Apache but what is it? Is it a port problem?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: How much RAM on your server?  # CPU's?  Can you limit worker threads to 8 rather than 64?

Comment: This url could be helpful for you  -  https://www.schlix.com/documentation/v2/configuration/troubleshooting-wamp-easyphp.html  - and this solution involves threadstacksize of WAMP.

Comment: WAMPServer has 3 servers, Apache, MySQL and MariaDB. That seems to be a valid Apache startup log So look at the logs for the other 2 servers

Comment: First identify which are servers then identify which server is not starting